# Microsoft Edge for iOS can’t Download Files

Tags: ios, download, blob, microsoft-edge, jspdf

Downloading files by jspdf and exceljs doesn't work in Edge for iOS.
I implemented downloading by link.
At first name and size of file define and downloading is starting, but after appeare 'Can't download'.
Maybe I don't have anything in http response header. Look at it, please:

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eyZq.png)

I tried downloading by adding Blob file to url using createObjectByUrl, but it's not supported by Edge for iOS.
Could you help me, please.

PS: Downloading works fine in Edge for Android and in Safari, Chrome for iOS, but doesn't work in Edge for iOS.

Comment: Which kind of file are you trying to download? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the text description and the screenshot, I can't locate the issue.

Comment: Can you show related codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your file from backend and send the stream to frontend, download it as a zip file.

It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).